# How to create a stateful encrypted connection between two C# applications?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, network-programming

I am currently looking for the best way to establish a stateful and encrypted connection between a C# client and server application. First, I thought about using IPsec, but as it works on a low level (OSI: Internet Layer), I would be very hard to implement, if you want the functionality inside your program and don't want to rely on the OS.

What technologies would you recommend for this purpose? Is there some functionality already built into .NET (4.5)? It does not neccessarily have to be stateful, working with some kind of heartbeat would be a valid option, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a standard protocol such as SSL rather than trying to make your own.  First the implementation will be much easier because the .NET framework will support it, and the transport protocol that runs underneath it is stateful (e.g. TCP).  Second developing a cryptographic protocol that is secure is very difficult, and SSL has already been implemented so why reinvent the wheel?

SSL works by using PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) to generate a shared symmetric key.  The handshake consists of a number of steps.  First the client sends a request for a secure session, then the server responds with it's certificate, the client verifies the certificate by crawling up the ladder through the certificate authorities (e.g. Verisign, Thawte, GeoTrust etc...) or if it already trusts the server it can just accept the certificate that is self signed.... and once it finds the certificate is trustworthy it generates a symmetric key and picks an algorithm (e.g. AES, 3DES, RC4, IDEA etc...).  The client then encrypts the key and algorithm being used with the public key, then the client sends that value to the server and a secure session can proceed using symmetric encryption which is much faster.

SSL itself is can be used in a stateful manner because it actually works over the transport layer in the OSI Model, HTTPS on the other hand is not a stateful protocol by design.  HTTPS is HTTP over SSL so the two technically don't really have anything to do with each other, except that in HTTPS SSL is used to secure the application data that is being requested.  With HTTPS as with HTTP once a request is made to the server it basically forgets about you (not exactly how it happens but for all intents and purposes you can think of it this way).  I myself would prefer the use of HTTPS if you can get around having to have a stateful protocol.  The main reason for doing so is so that I wouldn't have to write the code and possibly have a mistake in the implementation of SSL.  All you have to do is build a WCF or REST based service that runs on IIS and get a certificate for your server.

**That being said**, if you still want to create your own SSL server that doesn't use HTTP on the application level you can use the TcpListener and TcpClient classes along with the SslStream class provided as part of .NET to create your own.  MSDN has a good example of how to create an SSL server and client:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Side Notes**

- Securing the transport of your data does not secure your app, do not make the mistake of thinking you get automatic security
- If you choose to make your own server and client you can use either [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to generate your certificate or you can use [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which is part of .NET to make your certificate.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your detailed considerations! I tend to use SSL for our purposes, which is real-time data visualization and messaging in an industrial environment. Our existing messaging infrastructure components are based upon TcpListeners and TcpClients, so extending them with SSL is probably the most elegant and compatible way. I'll mark your post as solution soon, but let me keep the question open for some time, so others can add suggestions on this topic that might be of interest for others.

Answer (score 1):

Just form a regular TCP connection between the applications, and write up a simple packet protocol (EG, 4 bytes indicate packet size, followed by packet data)

Except the data within this base-level packet is encrypted through [`System.Cryptography.AesManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)

If you have trouble encrypting the packets using AesManaged, try using [The Encryptamajig](https://github.com/jbubriski/Encryptamajig) - if that doesn't help, post further questions and we'll give you further specific help.

-- You can either have both sides know the password ahead of time (EG, tell the person at the other end the password in person), or quickly pass it unencrypted at the start of the connection (or, rather, encrypted with a default known password)

Not necessarily the best method but it should do the job.

Comment: The problem with that is agreeing on a shared key and using AES correctly (no padding oracles etc.). So it's really hard to produce something secure with low level classes like `AesManaged`. The library you link isn't great either, unauthenticated encryption, and treating a parameter as password but calling it `key`. The way PBDFK2 is used isn't ideal either, but that isn't a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just the regular HTTPS? HTTP is just one level above TCP but it is far easier to work with and firewalls tend to be generally easy on HTTP/HTTPS ports namely 80 and 443. Of course, plain HTTP is not suitable for you but can you not use HTTPS instead of coming up with your own encrypted communication mechanism? In the client side (C#), all .NET classes such as HttpClient supports HTTPS very well. I quote [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/157282/why-tcp-is-evil-and-http-is-king) in support of my suggestion to go with HTTP :)