# Securing a c# program from debuggers and programs like wireshark

Tags: c#, security, debugging

I recently started a new project, and my issue is that I want to secure my program from getting attached by any kind of a debugger or getting watched by something that shows what data is going in and out (except the ip) like Wireshark.

I'm not sure how I should start with this, I already looked through a lot of forums for this.

My first attempt was to put it in front of every action like this, but I look for an easier way to do this with just 1-2 lines of code on every form

```
 if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == true) 
      this.close();
 else
     // run the rest of the program
```

but does this help against every and also against encrypted debuggers?

Or do I need to get some signatures of the programs ?

Would be nice to get some good tips

Thanks for any help

Comment: If a computer can execute your program, so can a debugger step through it. There's nothing you can do to prevent that. There are things like obfuscation that make it harder for a human to figure out what a program does, but it's pretty much the only thing you can do.

Comment: And if you send data over a wire, there's really nothing to stop Wireshark from trapping it. All you can potentially do is encrypt the payload, so that an attacker with Wireshark can see be packets - but not make sense of their contents

Comment: i search for a better way then mine that is executing the whole time, the programm is running and closing it if there is sth founded .

Comment: Also i try to apply the features u guys adviced me to add thx 4 help

Comment: Basically it's a fight between you and the person who wants to get to know what your application is doing and you. 

You should answer yourself one question - is there enough info in my app that someone would spend hours to crack it? 

If yes then you can only slow such person down. There are tricks - there are also anti-tricks. 

If not - just don't waste your time. You can obfuscate but there are de-obfuscators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you got two fronts there:

1) You can obfuscate your code following this tutorial. That will help you with the debbuger issues: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040107/Configuring-Visual-Studio-for-Obfuscation

2) For communication issues, you´ll have to encrypt your communication. As Wireshark kind of software works on another level, you won´t be able to avoid it. Depending on what type of communication your software is using and which are the endpoints, you can encrypt and decrypt on your other endpoint. In this post you get a good view of this: [How to create a stateful encrypted connection between two C# applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377664/how-to-create-a-stateful-encrypted-connection-between-two-c-sharp-applications)

Comment: so there isnt any way to detect a pub debugger ? and auto close the application ?

Comment: I´ve never done something like that. You can check if what is spotted in this post actually works for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188201/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-debugger-is-attached-to-a-process-from-c